# Taking a variable value from other function????? python

Tags: python

can anyone help me with this?

I have these two functions... I just want to bring the value **SP** to **create_ball_numbers**...
but always I have an error msg... (showed below)

```
class have_settings():

    def create_ball_speed(self, speed):
        self.the_ball_speed = speed
        self.sp = 0

        if self.the_ball_speed   == "slow":
            self.sp =  2
        elif self.the_ball_speed == "normal":
            self.sp = 4
        elif self.the_ball_speed == "fast":    
            self.sp =  6

    def create_ball_numbers(self, number):
        self.the_ball_number = number

        if self.the_ball_number in (1,2,3):
            for n in range(self.the_ball_number):

                self.position_x = random.randrange(10,734)
                self.position_y = random.randrange(10,200)

                self.ball_img = games.load_image("ball.jpg")
                self.ball = Bounce(image = self.ball_img,
                                   x = self.position_x,
                                   y = self.position_y,
                                   dx = sp,
                                   dy = -1)
                games.screen.add(self.ball)
```

ERROR MSG...

```
NameError: global name 'sp' is not defined
```

or

```
AttributeError: 'Application' object has no attribute 'sp'
```

Comment: `dx = sp` should be `dx = self.sp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do as @Benjamin said, but it is also considered good practice to have all of your global variables at the top of your class definition. Example:

```
class Foo:

    Bar = 0

    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.Bar = bar

    def doStuff(self):
        for i in xrange(10000):
            print(self.Bar)
```

Comment: worked well when i declared outside of the function... thanks

Comment: @user3132508 No problem, I always do this because it is mandatory in most languages, and it is also much more clear when you are reading it